# How to select a specific child by className in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

How to select a specific child by className in Tailwind?

I have tried some selectors but it seems nothing is matching, is it even possible?

```
<div className="[CHILD_CLASSNAME]:bg-red [NESTED_CHILD_CLASSNAME]:bg-blue">
   <div className="CHILD_CLASSNAME">
      text in red
      <div className="NESTED_CHILD_CLASSNAME">text in blue</div>
   </div>
<div>
```

note: I can't style directly child component with CHILD_CLASSNAME

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Arbitrary](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants) variants should contain `&` sign - it points on current element with this variant class

```html
<div class="[&_.CHILD-CLASSNAME]:bg-red-500 [&_.NESTED-CHILD-CLASSNAME]:bg-blue-500">
   <div class="CHILD-CLASSNAME">
      text in red
      <div class="NESTED-CHILD-CLASSNAME">text in blue</div>
   </div>
<div>
```

`&_.CHILD-CLASSNAME` simply will point on every element within as in regular CSS. You can use any CSS selector

Please note: if your class contains `_` in the class name, it should be escaped with `\` - otherwise Tailwind will consider it as a space

```html
<div class="[&_.CHILD_CLASSNAME]:bg-red-500 [&_.NESTED-CHILD-CLASSNAME]:bg-blue-500">
   <div class="CHILD_CLASSNAME">
      text in red (not working because of "_")
      <div class="NESTED-CHILD-CLASSNAME">text in blue</div>
   </div>
<div>

<div class="[&_.CHILD\_CLASSNAME]:bg-red-500 [&_.NESTED-CHILD-CLASSNAME]:bg-blue-500">
   <div class="CHILD_CLASSNAME">
      text in red
      <div class="NESTED-CHILD-CLASSNAME">text in blue</div>
   </div>
<div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/V5nIys4jOf)